# Nodejs && JSON: select value by key

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

I've this simple JSON:

```
{
    "list": [
        {"name": "item-1", "url": "http://item-1.com"},
        {"name": "item-2", "url": "http://item-2.com"},
        {"name": "item-3", "url": "http://item-3.com"}
    ]
}
```

I'm not able to get any url specifying name.
For example, if the nodejs program is called jsonpareser.js:

```
node jsonpareser.js "item-1"
```

I would like to print url "http://item-1.com".

Script in jsonparser.js is:

```
/* Get the parameter I want to search */
var item=process.argv.slice(2);

/* Specify JSON file path*/    
var file = './file.json';
/* Load file */
var items = require(file);

/* Iterate on elements */
for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    if ( typeof items[i] == item ) {
        console.log(items[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `jsonpareser.js` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not walking your data structure properly:

```
var items = require(file);

var list = items["list"];

for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    if ( list[i]["name"] == item ) {
        console.log(list[i]["url"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

You've added new code; i've fixed your "jsonparser.js" as well:

```
/* Get the parameter I want to search */
var item=process.argv.slice(2);

/* Specify JSON file path*/    
var file = './file.json';

/* Load file */
var items = require(file).list;

/* Iterate on elements */
for (var i in items)
{
    if (items[i].name==item)
    {
        console.log(items[i].url);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

use process.argv:

- arg 0: contains first argument, to run the code, which is "node"
- arg 1: contains second argument, path to run the code, which is [script-name]
- arg 2: must exist, will be your argument, "item-2" or undefined.

Hope this helps!

```
var list    =   
[
    {"name": "item-1", "url": "http://item-1.com"},
    {"name": "item-2", "url": "http://item-2.com"},
    {"name": "item-3", "url": "http://item-3.com"}
];

//  ensure at least TWO arguments are given
//  first argument is node=[script path]
if (process.argv.length>2)
{
    //  assume second argv contains your name.
    var name    =   process.argv[2];

    //  iterate list.
    for (var i in list)
    {
        //  check for a match.
        if (list[i].name==name)
        {
            //  print data to console.
            console.log(list[i].url);

            //  print with success.
            process.exit(0);
        }
    }

    //  end of search, no items found, end with exit code.
    console.log("No items found.");
    process.exit(1);
}

//  no argument given, error and exit.
console.log("No arguments given, please give an argument!");
process.exit(1);
```